# How can I ensure ZeroMQ doesn't block waiting for messages after sockets are closed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

This little test script shows my problem. It will send messages, close all sockets, and then just wait, never exiting. Supposedly setting ZMQ_LINGER to 0 is supposed to make it discard all queued messages immediately, so why isn't this allowing my Node.js process to exit?

```
const zmq = require('zmq')

const bindUrl = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4000'
let timer

let publisher = zmq.socket('pub')
publisher.monitor(500, 0)
publisher.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_LINGER, 0)
publisher.bind(bindUrl)

let subscriber = zmq.socket('sub')
subscriber.monitor(500, 0)
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_LINGER, 0)
subscriber.connect(bindUrl)

subscriber.on('connect_error', () => {
  console.log('connect error')
})

subscriber.on('connect', () => {
  subscriber.subscribe('some topic')
})

publisher.on('bind', function () {
  console.log('bound')
  timer = setInterval(() => publisher.send(['some topic', 'blah']), 1000)
})

publisher.on('bind_error', function () {
  console.log('bind error')
})

subscriber.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('subscriber disconnected')
  subscriber.close()
})

subscriber.on('close', function () {
  console.log('subscriber closed')
  subscriber.removeAllListeners()
  subscriber = null
})

publisher.on('unbind', function () {
  console.log('publisher unbound')
  publisher.close()
})

publisher.on('close', function () {
  console.log('publisher closed')
  publisher.removeAllListeners()
  publisher = null

  subscriber.disconnect(bindUrl)
})

subscriber.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  console.log(topic.toString(), message.toString())
  clearInterval(timer)
  subscriber.unsubscribe('some topic')
  publisher.unbind(bindUrl)
})
```

Output is the following, and the process never exits.

```
erin@titania:~/$ node test-disconnect.js 
bound
some topic blah
publisher unbound
publisher closed
subscriber disconnected
subscriber closed
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that I am explicitly monitoring the sockets is what caused this behavior. I have to explicitly call `socket.unmonitor` when I'm ready for the process to exit.